# Expected Value of the value of the width of the interval $(X,4X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

> Find the Expected Value of the value of the width of the interval $(X,4X)$

How do I find the Expected Value in this case since the interval consists of X, the problem is that the answer is an integer and not in terms of X.

My attempt is :

$$E(X)=F(4X)-F(2X)=(1-e^{-2X})-(1-e^{-X})=e^{-X}-e^{-2X}$$

Comment: Hint: regardless of the specific value taken on by $X$, the _interval_ $(X,4X)$ has _length_ $3X$: it "begins" just after $X$ and "ends" just before $4X$. Thus, you are asked for $E[3X]$, which happens to be the same as $3E[X]$, and No, $E[X]$ does _not_ equal $F(4X)-F(2X)$ as you try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $E(3X)$. This is $3E(X)$. One can find $E(X)$ directly from the cumulative distribution function. However, that may not have been covered in your course.

So to find $E(X)$, note that $X$ has density function $\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}$ (for $x\gt 0$). So $X$ has exponential distribution. You may know the mean of the exponential. Or else you can calculate it using
$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty x\cdot\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}\,dx.$$
To calculate the integral, use integration by parts.

**Remark:** For a non-negative random variable $X$ with continuous distribution, we have
$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))\,dx,$$
where $F_X(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. For some details, please [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values)
So for our case we have
$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank You! And, Calculation of directly is written as the Main answer in my course book whereas the integration method is written as the Alternative Method. Can you please please add the calculation of direct method :) Appreciate a lot

Comment: And the teacher didn't teach us a way to do without integration, but please please if you can add that into the answer, I want to know how it's done.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. For the integration by parts, let $u=x$ and $dv=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}\,dx$. Then $du=dx$ and we can let $v=-e^{-x/2}$. So the integral is $\left.-xe^{-x/2}\right|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}\,dx$. The first term is $0$.

Comment: No Sir, I know how to do integration by parts. What I am asking is you mentioned "one can find the expected value directly from the C.D.F" , Im asking how is that done ? :)

Comment: It is done (briefly) in the remark at the end of the answer. A sketch of the fact the formula (for non-negative random variables) is correct is given in the Wikipedia article linked to. It is near the end, Section 5.2.

Comment: You are welcome.